# Tag-page says I'm on featured tab, but that tab doesn't exist

Tags: bug, status-completed

Repro steps:

1. Click 'Questions'
2. Click 'featured'
3. Click the 'Arqade' site logo in the upper-left
4. Click on a tag
5. Now you see this:

[image: You are on the featured tab]

A minor bug, but I didn't see it reported before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed; that certainly *used* to work, but it looks like a cog fell out at some point... in 2013! This should be fixed next build.

Comment: Wow, you guys are responsive - thanks!